# Topology(norme vector space)

Tags: calculus, general-topology, analysis, algebraic-topology

Let $A, B$  two non-empty part of a normed vector space such that
$$
d(A,B)=\inf_{x\in A, \ y\in B}d(x,y)>0
$$
I need to Show that there exist two disjoint open $U$ and $V$ such that $A\subset U$ et $B\subset V$. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $a\in A$ let $r_a>0$ such that $d(a,b)>r_a$ for all $b\in B.$

For each $b\in B$ let $s_b>0$ such that $d(b,a)>s_b$ for all $a\in A.$

Let $U=\cup \{B(a,r_a/2):a\in A\}.$ Let $V=\cup \{B(b,s_b/2):b\in B\}.$

Suppose $z\in U\cap V.$ Then there exists $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ with $z\in B(a,r_a/2)\cap B(b,s_b/2).$ By the def'n of $r_a$ and the triangle inequality we have $$\bullet \;\; r_a<d(a,b)\leq d(a,z)+d(z,b)<r_a/2+s_b/2.$$ And by the def'n of $s_b$ and the triangle inequality we have $$\bullet \bullet \; \;  s_b<d(b,a)\leq d(b,z)+d(z,a)<s_b/2+r_a/2.$$ Adding the far left and far right sides of $\bullet$ and $\bullet \bullet$ we have $$r_a+s_b<(r_a/2+s_b/2)+(s_b/2+r_a/2)=r_a+s_b.$$ Which is absurd.

Remarks.(1). The existence of positive $r_a$ and $s_b$ for each $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ follows from  $A\cap \bar B=\phi=\bar A \cap B,$ which is a weaker (more general) condition than $\inf \{d(a,b):a\in A, b\in B\}>0.$ For example, in $\mathbb R^2$ let $A=\{(x,1/x):x\ne 0\}$ and $B=\{(x,-1/x):x\ne 0\}.$ ... (2). This applies in any metric space.